# The slow query with one innerjoin

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization, query-optimization

I have a querythat in a `foreach` loop search this query for every single `item`

but it is so slow.

```
foreach (string item in X)
{
   //This is the prototype 
    querystring = "select distinct g.N,g.NH + ' - ' + g.NV + ' - ' + g.S + ' - ' + g.VS ID
    from Table1 as g inner join Table2 as d on d.V=g.V
    where d.MD= '1234' and g.AC= 'item' and
       g.N <> '' and g.NV <> '' and g.S <> '' and g.VS <> '' ORDER BY g.N";
}
```

I ran `Estimated Execution Plan` , I can not attach the results here, but for Table 1 the `index seek(nonClustered)` cost is `40%` and the `parallelism (repartion streams) is 24%` the rest are all low.

Comment: Is a single query slow, or does it take a lot of time to process the `foreach`?

Comment: even the single query is slow, and foreach search max 20 times. but it is so slow. it take 4 to 7 seconds to give me the result

Comment: It's probably more efficient to fire a single query, and retrieve the relevant data per item in X in your C#(?) code.

Comment: I ran Estimated Execution Plan only for one item in fact

Comment: do you think if I would better write the foreach embedded in query?

Comment: No, I think you should first retrieve all data (perhaps limited by all items in X, depending on what that is), and split the data when you have it in memory.

Comment: @HoneyBadger would you please tell me how it works? I did not understand what should I do exactly

Comment: See my answer, you'll have to figure out the C# code yourself

Answer (score 0):

You are now firing up to 20 identical queries to the database (identical except for the `where` condition). So what I would do is fire one query like:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT g.N
,          g.NH + ' - ' + g.NV + ' - ' + g.S + ' - ' + g.VS ID
from       Table1 as g 
INNER JOIN Table2 as d 
        ON d.V=g.V
WHERE      d.MD= '1234' 
       AND g.N <> '' 
       AND g.NV <> '' 
       AND g.S <> '' 
       AND g.VS <> '' 
ORDER BY   g.N
```

And load the result in a variable of some sort, a `Dictionary` or a `Datatable` would seem your best bet.

When you have all your data in the variable, you can query the result for your individual Items in X. You could, for example, use `Linq` for that.

Also, I just copied your query, but all the string concatenation I would do in C# as well. So just select `g.NH` and `g.NV` and so on separately, and concatenate them where you need them.

Lastly, are you sure you need a `DISTINCT`? Usually when you have to use it, it means a `JOIN` condition is wrong/incomplete. It may be correct, just be sure it is.